# Performance between check exists before add to list and distinct in linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

In the foreach loop, I want to add the Products to a List, but I want this List to not contain duplicate Products, currently I have two ideas solved.

1/ In the loop, before adding the Product to the List, I will check whether the Product already exists in the List, otherwise I will add it to the List.

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    // code logic
    if(!listProduct.Any(x => x.Id == product.Id))
    {
        listProduct.Add(product);
    }
}
```

2/. In the loop, I will add all the Products to the List even if there are duplicate products. Then outside of the loop, I would use Distinct to remove duplicate records.

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    // code logic
        listProduct.Add(product);
}
listProduct  = listProduct.Distinct().ToList();
```

I wonder in these two ways is the most effective way. Or have any other ideas to be able to add records to the List to avoid duplication ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for a third approach: **the HashSet.** It has a constructor overload that accepts an `IEnumerable`. This constructor removes duplicates:

> If the input collection contains duplicates, the set will contain one
>   of each unique element. No exception will be thrown.

Source: [`HashSet<T>` Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

usage:

```
List<Product> myProducts = ...;
var setOfProducts = new HashSet<Product>(myProducts);
```

After removing duplicates there is no proper meaning of `setOfProducts[4]`.

Therefore a HashSet is not a `IList<Product>`, but an `ICollection<Product>`, you can Count / Add / Remove, etc, everything you can do with a List. The only thing you can't do is fetch by index

Answer (score 2):

You first take which elements are not already in the collection:

```
var newProducts = products.Where(x => !listProduct.Any(y => x.Id == y.Id));
```

And then just add them using AddRang

```
listProduct.AddRagne(newItems)
```

Or you can use foreach loop too

```
foreach (var product in newProducts)
{
    listProduct.Add(product);
}
```

1 more easy solution could be there no need to use `Distint`

```
 var newProductList = products.Union(listProduct).ToList();
```

But Union has not good performance.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have included, you are storing everything in memory. If this is the case, or you are persisting only after you have it ready you can consider using BinarySearch: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx and you also get an ordered list at the end. If ordering is not important, you can use HashSet, which is very fast, and meant specially for this purpose.

Check also: https://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty fast and take care of any ordering:

```
// build a HashSet of your primary keys type (I'm assuming integers here) containing all your list elements' keys
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(listProduct.Select(p => p.Id));

// add all items from the products list whose Id can be added to the hashSet (so it's not a duplicate)
listProduct.AddRange(products.Where(p => hashSet.Add(p.Id)));
```

What you might want to consider doing instead, though, is implementing [`IEquatable<Product>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) and overriding [`GetHashCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `Product` type which would make the above code a little easier and put the equality checks where they should be (inside the respective type):

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(listProduct);
listProduct.AddRange(products.Where(hashSet.Add));
```